Breakup List of file filters in FileOpenDialog
I have a function to open a list of files with filters and after selecting one, it opens in the default program for the file type. I want to break the filter list up so I have one per line as I'm going to have quite a few but it isn't working with the normal backtick. If I do them all on a single line, it works fine. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried doing it before and after the pipe but it made no difference. If I set it to all files I see Word documents but if I set it to *.docx they don't show. The same for *.xlsx files and *.csvs they show up in the filter dialog but they just aren't being read. Can this be done or do I Have to do them all on the same line?
function Open-FileDialog {
        [cmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
            [String]
            $InitialDirectory
        )
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog 
    if($InitialDirectory){
        $FileBrowser.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    }

    else{
    $fileBrowser.InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
    }$FileBrowser.Filter = 'SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx`
    |Document (*.docx)|*.docx`
    |CSV (*.csv)|*.csv`
    |All Files (*.*)|*.*'

[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FileBrowser.FileName

}

$file = Open-FileDialog
Invoke-item $file


Backticks ` aren't recognized as a separator. From FileDialog.Filter Remarks:

For each filtering option, the filter string contains a description of the filter, followed by the vertical bar (|) and the filter pattern. The strings for different filtering options are separated by the vertical bar.

What you can do to keep it clean is an array that is later on joined by | with -join operator. This way you can add or remove more filters quite easily.
$FileBrowser.Filter = @(
    'SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'
    'Document (*.docx)|*.docx'
    'CSV (*.csv)|*.csv'
    'All Files (*.*)|*.*'
) -join '|'

